# Ink label kanji?

Tags: translation, kanji, colors

So I was looking at a modular kit that was made in Japan, and inside of the box were some ink labels (I think CMYK). Here is a picture:
[image: Ink labels]

I recognized three of the four kanji. The first being 墨 (black ink), third as 赤 (red), and the fourth as 黄 (yellow), but I cannot seem to recognize the second label. I have looked by radical and in the WWWJDIC dictonary by Jim Breen and could not find it. Could someone tell me what this is? I used the search terms "blue", "azure", and "cyan".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's 藍 -- the character for indigo.

Comment: [藍色](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%97%8D%E8%89%B2) seems to tend to blue rather than violet compared to [indigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigo). Natural indigo seems to be what is indicated here.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is actually Japanese. The normal terms for CYMK ink colours are シアン : イエロー : マゼンタ : クロ, whereas these appear to be the Chinese words for "Black, Blue, Red, Yellow". (I don't know much Chinese, but the first entry for 青い in a J-C dictionary is 藍.) If you look at the Chinese Wikipedia article https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%B0%E5%88%B7%E5%9B%9B%E5%88%86%E8%89%B2%E6%A8%A1%E5%BC%8F you will see that these do not match the standard Chinese terminology either. Something makes me think that these were generated in a country which does not speak either Japanese or Chinese, by asking someone who did not know anything about printing.

Comment: The kit said it was manufactured in Japan, and also this was purchased in about the early '70s, so that could possibly make a difference.

Comment: I don't see any reasons for Japanese people to do not write 墨、藍、赤 and 黄 on ink labels, even considering that  シアン 、 イエロー、 マゼンタ and クロ are common in the spoken language.

Comment: 「[コトバンク・日本大百科全書『多色印刷』](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A4%9A%E8%89%B2%E5%8D%B0%E5%88%B7-849952)」によれば、「黒（ **印刷では墨という。** ブラックblack）のほかに、たとえば赤を入れるような2色印刷や、さらに青を入れるような3色印刷も多色印刷であり、**黄** （イエローyellow）、**赤** （紅、マゼンタmagenta）、 **藍** (あい)（シアンcyan）の3色に**墨**を加えた、いわゆる原色版印刷も多色印刷である。」、また、このページ→「[印刷インキの基礎知識](http://homepage2.nifty.com/t-nakajima/kamikiso210.html)」によれば、「この4色をカラー印刷の基準インキ（プロセスインキ）といい、ブラック、シアン、マゼンタ、イエローを印刷ではそれぞれ、スミ（ **墨** ）、アイ（ **藍** ）、アカ（ **赤** ）、キ（ **黄** ）と呼びます。」だそうですよ。

Comment: In that case I am completely wrong. Certainly writing 墨 for black seems reasonable; but using 藍色 (a deep, purplish blue) to refer to cyan (blue-green) does seem extremely odd. (But this terminology is often confused: my book does not agree with the other, but has confusion of its own, using 赤 for both red and magenta.)